How does delta lake guarantee exactly once processing when ingesting data from Kafka?
This doc suggests that Delta Lake guarantees exactly once processing.
How does Delta Lake distinguish between 2 identical transactions (insert the same row twice) and a client retry of previous transaction that failed due to network error (but actually successfully committed on the server side)?

As per their doc, "exactly-once" guarantee means row will be saved to output table just one time, even if there are concurrent writes. Their doc does not mention Kafka

The doc was about streaming writes using spark structured streaming I think.
